# AS3 Flash Compile - Exclude Functions from Compile

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

There is probably no way for this but does anyone know a method of excluding certain functions from a build by use of a meta tag and or compiler option?

I want to expose some functions for testing but not have them bloat the application on production. I could create separate testing classes and test for a complier directive or option and only load them if necessary but I like the idea of having the test function on the actual object (in the class).

Thanks

Ronan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look at [conditional compilation](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/conditionalcompilation.pdf) for example look to this blog post http://www.pixelate.de/blog/debug-and-release-builds-with-as3-conditional-compilation

Answer (score 3):

You can use [conditional compilation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html) for that.